# Redux edit todo

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm learning Redux.

Can someone explain step-by-step how to add edit functionality on this example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxQOaw?editors=0010

I have added actions and reducers but not sure how to pass it on the stateless components.

Action:

```
export const editTodo = (text) => {
    const action = {
      type: 'EDIT_TODO'
    }
    console.log('action in editTodo', action);
    return action;
}
```

Reducer:

```
const todo = (state, action) => {   switch (action.type) {
    case 'EDIT_TODO':
      if (state.id !== action.id) {
        return state;
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        text: action.text
      };
    default:
      return state;   } }; const todos = (state = [], action) => {   switch (action.type) {
    case 'EDIT_TODO':
      return state.map(t =>
        todo(t, action)                
      );

    default:
      return state;   } }
```

Do I need to convert those stateless components into classes?

Answer (score -1):

You should collect all your redux reducers into one giant reducer using combineReducers

```
import ToDoReducer from './todo-reducer.js';
import OtherReducer from './other-reducer.js';
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    ToDo:ToDoReducer,
    OtherR:OtherReducer,
});

export default allReducers;
```

Then in your root file, apply the combined redux reducer through the react-rudux provider.

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const store = createStore(allReducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));

class App extends React.Component{
render(){
    return(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <YourSecondaryMainComponent />
        </Provider>
    )
}
....
```

Then you can use them in your components with connect and bindActionCreators.

```
import React from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import editTodo from './todoFunctions.js';

class myComponent extends React.Component{
   ...
}

let mapStateToProps = (state)=>{return {ToDo:state.ToDo}; };
let matchDispatchToProps = (dispatch)=>{ return bindActionCreators({ editTodo }, dispatch); }
export default connect(mapStateToProps,matchDispatchToProps)(myComponent);
```

Comment: Emad, why are you using `redux-thunk` in your answer? The OP is not making an asynchronous request to edit his todo list.

Comment: Daniel, yes you're right, I missed that. At least he has it now if he needs it.